# Vlookup for dates in other sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem! Even though my Vlookup for dates seems to be fine, when I run the macro, instead of showing dates, it shows some random numbers! Below is the code for vlookup! I did not include the rest of the code because it has nothing to do with this part! The vlookup is correct as of where it refers to and staff beacuse in the sheets it runs perfectly as a formula.. Only inside a macro is not working!! Should I add anything to the code below to indicate that it is a date so as for the macro to behave differently? please help me :)

```
Sheets("Tracker1").Select
    lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G2:G" & lastrow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,'Programare'!C:F,4,FALSE))"
```

Comment: Format Cells -> Date - You don't need VBA for this - just format the entire column as a date. If you prefer to use vba, you can add: `Range("G2:G" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"` before your `Range("G2...` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set explicitly the format to the dat format you want. i.e.

```
With Worksheets("Tracker1")
  lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  With .Range("G2:G" & lastrow)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,'Programare'!C:F,4,FALSE))"
    .NumberFormat = "d/m/yy"  ' <---------------------- Set the date format explicitly
  End With
End With
```

Comment: A.S.H Thank you from the bottom of my heart!!! I was literally desperate the past 2 days trying to figure this out !! you saved me from HUGE trouble!! Thanks again!!